# If $g(16) = 16$, then compute $\log_2 g(4)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are functions which satisfy $f(g(x)) = x^2$ and $g(f(x)) = x^3$ for all $x \ge 1$. If $g(16) = 16$, then compute $\log_2 g(4)$. (You may assume that $f(x) \ge 1$ and $g(x) \ge 1$ for all $x \ge 1$.)

---

I am stuck on this problem.  I don't see any strategy that may help me.  Is there something going on with the log?  Any solution is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=g(4)$. Then
$$ x^3 = g(f(x))) = g(f(g(4))) = g(4^2) = g(16) = 16 $$

Comment: How should I proceed from there?

Comment: @Yuna: You mean, once you know what $x^3$ is, how would you find $\log_2(x)$?

Comment: Is the answer $\frac{4}{3}$?

Comment: @YunaKun: That's what I get, at least.